# WSL error 0x80370102 while installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am getting error 0x80370102 while installing Ubuntu.

- I have enabled Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform and Windows Subsystem for Linux. I disabled them, rebooted and re-enabled, rebooted and tried again with the same result.
- Virtualization is enabled in UEFI.
- I am able to create VMs in Hyper-V but not able to run them.
- WSL1 works fine.
- I have run WSL2 before on this computer so the hardware is supported.
- No other virtualization software.

[screenshot of error](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86760472/147668238-d5388cc6-aec6-4f04-aeac-69b8fbb3fe43.png)
[screenshot of task manager](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86760472/147676339-28654cc4-f67c-4f8d-a4c2-296bd1c51fc6.png)
[screenshot of Hyper-V error](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86760472/147676872-431d7f56-9fd9-4a83-bf07-1159fc492feb.png)
[screenshot of services.msc](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86760472/147677128-96e62c23-9e05-4433-a6d7-8946f33d3271.png)

Windows version: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1415]
WSL Kernel version: 5.10.60.1

Relevant output of `get-windowsoptionalfeature -online`:

```
FeatureName : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
State       : Enabled

FeatureName : HypervisorPlatform
State       : Enabled

FeatureName : VirtualMachinePlatform
State       : Enabled
```

Output of `bcdedit /v`:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {5552da70-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
resumeobject            {5552da6f-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
displayorder            {5552da70-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {5552da70-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {3b397448-f27e-11eb-9d80-ffe132952db6}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {5552da6f-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

Output of `coreinfo64`:

```
Coreinfo v3.52 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 000000CC
HTT             *       Hyperthreading enabled
CET             -       Supports Control Flow Enforcement Technology
Kernel CET      -       Kernel-mode CET Enabled
User CET        -       User-mode CET Allowed
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM             -       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64             *       Supports 64-bit mode

SMX             -       Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT          -       Supports AMD SKINIT
SGX             -       Supports Intel SGX

NX              *       Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB         *       Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE             *       Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT             *       Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE             *       Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36           *       Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE             *       Supports global bit in page tables
SS              *       Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME             *       Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    *       Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU             *       Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX             *       Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT          -       Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW           -       Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT        -       Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE             *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3           *       Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4a           -       Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
SSE4.1          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES             *       Supports AES extensions
AVX             *       Supports AVX instruction extensions
AVX2            *       Supports AVX2 instruction extensions
AVX-512-F       -       Supports AVX-512 Foundation instructions
AVX-512-DQ      -       Supports AVX-512 double and quadword instructions
AVX-512-IFAMA   -       Supports AVX-512 integer Fused multiply-add instructions
AVX-512-PF      -       Supports AVX-512 prefetch instructions
AVX-512-ER      -       Supports AVX-512 exponential and reciprocal instructions
AVX-512-CD      -       Supports AVX-512 conflict detection instructions
AVX-512-BW      -       Supports AVX-512 byte and word instructions
AVX-512-VL      -       Supports AVX-512 vector length instructions
FMA             *       Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR             *       Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR            *       Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE           *       Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE         *       Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND          *       Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED          *       Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV            *       Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH           *       Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8             *       Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16            *       Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
ADX             *       Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA             -       Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C            *       Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR            *       Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR           -       Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR         -       Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE           *       Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB           *       Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLMULDQ        *       Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT          *       Supports POPCNT instruction
LZCNT           *       Supports LZCNT instruction
SEP             *       Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF       *       Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE             -       Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM             -       Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE              *       Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64          *       Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS              *       Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL          -       Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID            *       Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID         *       Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM            *       Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP          *       Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC             *       Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    -       Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *       TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR            *       Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST            *       Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI            *       Implements MSR for power management
TM              *       Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2             *       Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC            *       Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC          -       Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID         -       L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE             *       Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA             *       Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE             *       Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN             -       Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW       *       Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 00000016 (Basic), 80000008 (Extended).
Maximum implemented address width: 48 bits (virtual), 39 bits (physical).

Processor signature: 000406E3

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**--  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
****  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
****  NUMA Node 0

No NUMA nodes.

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
**--  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**--  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**--  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
****  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,    3 MB, Assoc  12, LineSize  64
--**  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
****  Group 0
```

ETL: [wsl.etl](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuOB0Lk4djILmZRbuOVx_-bwymttWw)

Comment: @Ramhound Already mentioned that in question. I have already tried that, the feature is enabled.

Comment: As I expected you have software that is interfering with Hyper-V being fully functional.  Do you by chance have VirtualBox, VMware, Android Emulator, Docker, or any other application that might be using the VT-x hardware virtualization installed on your system? Please provide the output of `bcdedit /v`, the output of that command, will help us diagnose your problem

Comment: You also will have to download [Core Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo) and verify your processor supports SLAT.

Comment: The processor does support SLAT, as I've said I've run WSL2 on it before. I've also run Hyper-V VMs on it before.

Comment: The error code is indicating something isn’t enabled or supported. There has to be a reason

Comment: It does, I've run both WSL2 and normal Hyper-V VMs on it before (including Windows VMs).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132703/discussion-between-ramhound-and-abhate).

Comment: @Ramhound I was able to fix my issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue myself following these steps:

1. Open Windows Security.
2. Go to App & Browser Control.
3. Go to Exploit protection settings.
4. Go to Program settings.
5. Set `C:\Windows\System32\vmcompute.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\vmwp.exe` to 0 system overrides.
6. Restart these processes.

Now I am able to run VMs as well as install WSL2 distros.

Comment: thank you! this is great