# coreinfo says processor does not support VMX when it actually does

Tags: windows-10, cpu, virtualization

Output from `coreinfo64`:

```
Coreinfo v3.52 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 000000CC
HTT             *       Hyperthreading enabled
CET             -       Supports Control Flow Enforcement Technology
Kernel CET      -       Kernel-mode CET Enabled
User CET        -       User-mode CET Allowed
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM             -       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64             *       Supports 64-bit mode

SMX             -       Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT          -       Supports AMD SKINIT
SGX             -       Supports Intel SGX

NX              *       Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB         *       Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE             *       Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT             *       Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE             *       Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36           *       Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE             *       Supports global bit in page tables
SS              *       Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME             *       Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    *       Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU             *       Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX             *       Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT          -       Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW           -       Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT        -       Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE             *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3           *       Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4a           -       Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
SSE4.1          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES             *       Supports AES extensions
AVX             *       Supports AVX instruction extensions
AVX2            *       Supports AVX2 instruction extensions
AVX-512-F       -       Supports AVX-512 Foundation instructions
AVX-512-DQ      -       Supports AVX-512 double and quadword instructions
AVX-512-IFAMA   -       Supports AVX-512 integer Fused multiply-add instructions
AVX-512-PF      -       Supports AVX-512 prefetch instructions
AVX-512-ER      -       Supports AVX-512 exponential and reciprocal instructions
AVX-512-CD      -       Supports AVX-512 conflict detection instructions
AVX-512-BW      -       Supports AVX-512 byte and word instructions
AVX-512-VL      -       Supports AVX-512 vector length instructions
FMA             *       Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR             *       Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR            *       Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE           *       Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE         *       Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND          *       Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED          *       Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV            *       Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH           *       Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8             *       Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16            *       Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
ADX             *       Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA             -       Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C            *       Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR            *       Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR           -       Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR         -       Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE           *       Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB           *       Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLMULDQ        *       Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT          *       Supports POPCNT instruction
LZCNT           *       Supports LZCNT instruction
SEP             *       Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF       *       Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE             -       Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM             -       Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE              *       Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64          *       Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS              *       Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL          -       Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID            *       Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID         *       Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM            *       Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP          *       Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC             *       Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    -       Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *       TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR            *       Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST            *       Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI            *       Implements MSR for power management
TM              *       Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2             *       Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC            *       Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC          -       Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID         -       L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE             *       Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA             *       Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE             *       Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN             -       Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW       *       Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 00000016 (Basic), 80000008 (Extended).
Maximum implemented address width: 48 bits (virtual), 39 bits (physical).

Processor signature: 000406E3

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**--  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
****  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
****  NUMA Node 0

No NUMA nodes.

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
**--  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**--  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**--  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
****  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,    3 MB, Assoc  12, LineSize  64
--**  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
****  Group 0
```

Output of `bcdedit /v`:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {5552da70-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
resumeobject            {5552da6f-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
displayorder            {5552da70-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {5552da70-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {3b397448-f27e-11eb-9d80-ffe132952db6}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {5552da6f-e75f-11eb-89e7-b655d79896f6}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

The processor is an Intel Core i5-6200U which according to the Intel documentation supports VMX. `hypervisorlaunchtype` is set to `auto` in `bcdedit`, Task Manager says virtualization is enabled and so does the UEFI. Also I have run Hyper-V VMs on this machine on this particular install of Windows 10 so I know this processor does support VMX. Due to this no longer being detected, now I am unable to run Hyper-V VMs or WSL2 distros. Note that this is a physical machine and not a VM.

I have no other virtualization software. Only Hyper-V is installed. The only antivirus installed is Windows Defender.

Windows version: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1415]`

I uninstalled Hyper-V but no change in `coreinfo64`. However, one thing I noticed is that the "vEthernet (Default Switch)" still shows up in Task Manager. I think maybe some component of Hyper-V may be left, but I am unable to find it.

I ran `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and now `coreinfo64` says VMX is supported. Now I'll reinstall Hyper-V and check if I can run VMs. Nope, can't run VMs. Seems setting it to `auto` will not allow `coreinfo64` to show VMX as supported and setting it to `off` still does not allow me to run Hyper-V.

Comment: If CoreInfo64 is indicating that your processor does NOT support VT-x it means you have some application installed already using it. So what software do you have installed? Uninstall ALL software that might be using it including Hyper-V until CoreInfo64 indicates your processor does support it. If you have for instance Docker, VMWare Workstation, VirtualBox, Android Emulator, or any similar application installed you will be told your processor doesn’t support VT-x by CoreInfo64. Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: This, and check the firmware (UEFI on anything modern, or BIOS on decade old stuff). The CPU can support it, but if disabled in motherboard firmware or already in use then you have a challenge.

Comment: @Hennes I have already said in the question that it is enabled in UEFI. Please read the whole thing.

Comment: @abhate - Do you have Core Isolation enabled? You can always try `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype on` instead of `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`, but I would rather provide your current boot configuration data before try either command.  If you run the command to explictly turn it on, then provided an updated output of CoreInfo64, by editing your question

Comment: @Ramhound added output of `bcdedit /v`. `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype on` is not the valid data type and thus gives an error.

Comment: "Seems setting it to auto will not allow coreinfo64 to show VMX as supported" - It's not supposed to show it as being supported if you set it to auto.  It showing up as disabled while `hypervisorlaunchtype` is set to auto is desired behavior.  You never indicated if Core Isolation was enabled or disabled. Since `auto` works (instead of `on`) set it back to `auto` for the time being.

Comment: You should also verify that Virtualization-based Security (VBS) is disabled.

Comment: @abhate - Just to confirm. If you run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and run the same command `bcdedit /v` it shows that `hypervisorlaunchtype` is `off` instead of `auto` correct?

Comment: @Ramhound `bcdedit /v` shows it as `off` after running `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and rebooting. Also, the only setting in Core Isolation is Memory Integrity and that is disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound I was able to solve my issue. [See my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1699260/1646406).