# WSL2 error 0x80370102 when trying to install ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am struggling to get WSL2 working. I had it working before but had to disabled Hyper-V in the past and such for something else to work and now I can't get it running again.

I have posted my windows features that I have enabled below

[image]

I have hypervisor enabled automatically

[image]

My bios has SVM enabled too

[image]

I am pretty stumped on what I need to enable/disable as it never provides any information on what is not working. Any help is appreciated

**Update**

I have tried creating a VM in Hyper-V manager and I get the error message saying one of the components is not running but I am not sure which one.

[image]

Comment: Anything in the Event Viewer regarding Hyper-V or Virtual Machine Platform?  As a test, you may want to try creating a new VM directly through Hyper-V Manager to see if the problem is truly in the hypervisor (I assume it is, but you seem to be doing all the right things, so verifying might not be a bad idea).

Comment: Also, are you using any other virtualization technology such as VirtualBox, VMWare, Android emulation (other than WSA), etc.?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I used to have VirtualBox but I have removed it. As far as I am aware it is uninstalled but I'm not sure if there are any remnants left. I have tried creating a VM in the hyper-v manager and I get an error that one of the hyper-v components is not running.

Comment: Whatever that component is, that's the one I'd be looking for in event-viewer.  That *might/hopefully* starting pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: I mean it literally says "The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'Test' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running". Microsoft are very vague with this stuff. I couldn't find much in event viewer though I'm probably looking in the wrong place

Comment: Agreed - That's not a very descriptive message :-/.  Grasping at straws here - What virus/threat protection is in place on the PC?  Any chance that it is preventing the startup of something?  I know things were working before disabling/reenabling Hyper-V, so I'm guessing that's not it, but as I said, grasping ...

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yeah I understand it's pretty hard to figure out this issue. I have no AV on my computer. I think I will have to ask on the microsoft forums or contact their support. I COULD reinstall but that does not solve the issue.

Comment: Ah, forgot to come back to this.  Any luck at all?  Just want to double-check that there is no AV at all?  Even the built-in Windows Defender can cause issues with WSL2 if the "Ransomware Protection" feature is enabled.

Comment: (1) Is Windows fully updated? (2) Are the distributions stored on the system drive? (3)   Check Dynamic Memory allocation is enabled in elevated PowerShell `Set-VMProcessor <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`, (4) Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1699260/8672).

Comment: @harrymc I had tried those things and it was all supposedly as it should be. I appreciate the help but I decided to do the Reset PC that windows provides.

Comment: @Emobe Good to hear it's working, at least.  I just came back to your question because I ran across the Event Viewer logs that show WSL starting up - For future reference if needed (and hopefully you won't need them again), they are in the Event Viewer under *Application and Services Logs* -> *Microsoft* -> *Windows* -> *Hyper-V Computer*.  I can see the logs where WSL2 creates the virtual machine.

Comment: On the bright side, between the votes on the question and your self-answer, you've almost gained the bounty back in reputation ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this I just had to perform the "Reset PC" that Windows provides.

It is not an ideal answer but I have asked in multiple places and nobody had a clue.

Answer (score -1):

okay edited the answer for the right answer:

in PowerShell as administrator:

```
Remove-WindowsFeature Hyper-V
```

or in in the machine itself:

[image]

after you reboot the computer re-add the role again and it should work for you.

Comment: Nothing happens with either of them

Comment: @Emobe check my edited answer again.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is more of a way of diagnosing a problem by completely changing the answer each time. None of these worked with me.